# how to call privileged method in another privileged method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one class with 2 privileged methods :

```
function ABC() {
     this.methodA = function(){

     }
     this.methodB = function(){

     }
}
```

Is it possible to call `methodA` inside `methodB`, if so how to call that?

Comment: `this.methodA()` doesn't work you mean?

Comment: You didn't share the code that actually calls your methods, so that makes it hard to help out.

Comment: @Jack, that's ok Jack. It solved ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ABC() {
     var self = this;
     this.methodA = function(){

     }
     this.methodB = function(){
         self.methodA();
     }
}
```

Comment: We cannot use `this.methodA()` ?

Comment: `this.methodA()` is valid. `this` refers to `ABC`, not `methodB`. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/8mSR3/) for an example.

Comment: @ThomasUpton : I tried it, then `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method methodA()` occured.

Comment: I just updated the link to the jsfiddle. It's working for me. How are you instantiating an instance of `ABC`?

Comment: `var i = new Cart();`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you need a reference to it. If `methodB` will always be called with the same context, then you can just call `methodA` from `methodB` using `this.methodA();`:

```
var a = new ABC;
a.methodB(); // Correctly calls methodA();

var func = a.methodB;
func(); // Fails because `this` is not referring to `a` anymore
```

It will work both ways if you do something like this:

```
function ABC() {
     var methodA = this.methodA = function(){

     }
     this.methodB = function(){
         methodA();
     }
}
```

Comment: Which one is better between create a private property `var self = this;` then call `methodB` by `self.methodB` and a private function as u did above?

Comment: @titi In general is not better that the other. One creates a reference to the object `this` and the other creates a reference just to the function. If you wanted to prevent `methodB` from calling `this.methodC();` then the way I posted is better, if you want to allow it then using `var self = this;` is beter.